# IOS Sprite Kit 2 Objects collide and stay put

Tags: sprite-kit

I want objects of the same category to not bounce off or be moved when they collide with one another.  I've tried playing around with collisionBitMask, contactTestBitMask, mass, density, etc.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypeRock;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypeRock;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypeRock;
```

Thanks.

Comment: set body velocities to zero in contact delegate method

Comment: Still didn't work.  The rock that got moved back.

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    [contact.bodyA setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
    [contact.bodyB setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
}

Comment: Is it okay if the rocks pass through one another?

Comment: Actually, let me give a better example of what I'm trying to do.  Think of those logic puzzle games like the blocks or cars being blocked in in a parking lot.  the idea is to move the other cars around so that you can move your car out of the lot.  So, when the car moves it should not be able to move the other cars when it hits it.  I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: You can stop the rocks from moving by setting their dynamic properties to NO in didBeginContact. You will need to set the velocities to zero as well, so they don't continue to move when you want them to move again by setting the dynamic properties to YES. BTW, how are you moving the rocks?

Comment: It's giving an assertion error:

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {   
contact.bodyA.dynamic = NO;  
contact.bodyB.dynamic = NO;  
[contact.bodyA setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];   
[contact.bodyB setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];   

}   
  
Assertion failed: (typeA == b2_dynamicBody || typeB == b2_dynamicBody), function SolveTOI, file /SourceCache/PhysicsKit_Sim/PhysicsKit-6.5.4/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp, line 678.  

The rocks move by user touch.

Comment: I guess you can't set the dynamic property once a contact has been made. Setting the velocity to zero should stop the rocks from moving. What happens when you do that? What does "The rock that got moved back" mean?

Comment: the rock that was hit was pushed back. btw thanks for helping me out.

Comment: That won't happen if you set self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0.